# JS function is not executed without using Alert box

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2013

I am stuck at one point doing JScripting in CRM. I know that problem is with JScript sync/async code execution flow. There is a html control on CRM page which loads some images from DB and displays them. Also, there is an option to manually upload images.

When user uploads an image manually, following function is executed:

```
function processingImage() {
var list = document.getElementById("image-list");
var imageList = list.getElementsByTagName('img');
var status = false;
for (var i = 0; i < imageList.length; i++) {
    var imageSource = imageList[i].src;
    var imageName = imageList[i].alt;
    var imageTypeSection = imageSource.split(";")[0];
    var imageType = imageTypeSection.split(":")[1];

    saveImage(imageSource, imageType, "sampleImage-" + imageName);
    status = true;
}
if (status) {
    //alert("Saved successfully.");
}
return status;
}
```

You see that there is an alert box of Saved Successfully in this function. The problem is when I display this alert, ONLY then image get saved in DB and it is displayed after page refresh. If I comment out alert box (as in this case) then image does not save into db neither it is showed on the control.

I have no idea how to resolve this issue. Please help.

Comment: I have resolved this issue and I beieve that information i gave is insufficient for someone to answer this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use java script function   `setTimeout` and see if i works or not.

```
function processingImage() {
var list = document.getElementById("image-list");
var imageList = list.getElementsByTagName('img');
var status = false;
for (var i = 0; i < imageList.length; i++) {
    var imageSource = imageList[i].src;
    var imageName = imageList[i].alt;
    var imageTypeSection = imageSource.split(";")[0];
    var imageType = imageTypeSection.split(":")[1];

    saveImage(imageSource, imageType, "sampleImage-" + imageName);
    status = true;
}
if (status) {
    //alert("Saved successfully.");
}
return status;
}


function timeout_init() {
    setTimeout('processingImage()', 2000);
}
```

now call `timeout_init` instead of `processingImage` , hopefully this may solve your problem